# Finding Future probability of results within a group of numbers

Tags: probability

I apologize in advance if this question, or one similar, has been asked - I couldn't find anything via a quick search.

How do I go about finding the probability of any particular number from within a group to be picked? I'm pretty sure I can figure out how to determine the weighted values of each number's selection when compared to the total number of resulting draws, but I'm not sure how to go forward and determine how those percentages would relate to the probability of any specific number being chosen again in future draws.

IE: If i have a group of 1-10; and taken over 100 draws; I can calculate the percentage of times that any specific number has been chosen from within those 100 draws (pretty basic.) What I'm not sure how to do is calculate the probability of any specific number being chosen in the NEXT 100 draws.

I wasn't a math slouch back in my school days, but I'm far removed from them now. Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.  If you believe that each draw is independent (and always taken from the same distribution) then over time the observed percentages should approach the actual probabilities.  In most "real world" situations, of course, you start with some kind of model for what the expected distribution is (or at least, what shape it should have).

Comment: The probability is not dependent on what happened before, assuming independency.